# An example of a function with following asymptotes

Tags: functions, asymptotics, graphing-functions

I am looking for a function which behaves in the following way:
$$f(x)\approx x^{-7/3}\text{ at x>3}$$
and
$$f(x)\approx x^{-4/3}\text{ at x<1}$$
I want to get a log-log plot of the function so that the two asymptotes are linear. I want a smooth curvy connection between $x=1$ and $x=3$. Any ideas on what kind of function will do that?

Comment: $\displaystyle{1\over x^{4/3}+x^{7/3}}$?

Comment: Right. That was a stupid question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand how the proposal of Neretin is satisfactory for you:  in the vicinity of $1$ his function is equivalent to $1/2$.

Comment: I only want proper asymptotes, and mathematica plot of the function that was suggested indeed gives what I am looking for.

Comment: @JeanMarie OP probably means as $x\to-\infty$ for $x<1$.

Comment: @Simple Art Thank for decoding. But what is the interest of the values $x=1$ and $x=3$ he has given ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Absolutely no idea.  It is rather vague.

Comment: It was supposed to be some random numbers. I am not concerned too much about the boundaries $x=1$ and $x=3$. It could as well be $x=0.5$ and $x=100$.